# Django Query results get all values of same field

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a way to get all the values of a field form queryset without looping through and adding to array?

I would do like below as simple example.

I have a Report class with a visit FK field.

```
results = Report.objects.all()

visits = []
for res in results:
   visits.append(res.visit)
```

But is there as a way to do something like:

visits = results.visit (and have the same result i would from query loop above).

Edit:

Classes below.

```
class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    planned_date = models.DateTimeField()
    visit = models.ForeignKey(ReportVisit)

class ReportVisit(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.CharField()
    time_in = models.DateTimeField()
    lat_in = models.CharField()
    long_in = models.CharField()
```

Comment: Please share your `Report` model and the model of `res.visit`.

Comment: I have edited to include. I have cut out the stuff I don't think is needed.

Comment: did you specify a `related_name` in your `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `Visit` model with:

```
ReportVisit.objects.filter(report__isnull=False).distinct()
```

the [**`.distinct()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will prevent retrieving the same `Visit` as many times as there are related `Report` objects. You can omit this if you want to retrieve the same `ReportVisit` once per `Report`.

Comment: Ok, i have actually used similar before but in different use case. I just need to filter based on known set of reports though which im unsure of. Example: results = Report.objects.filter(filters), and get the visits from there. Sorry, i should have put that in question but i didnt think of this way as a solution.

Comment: @Spirconi: you can still do that. You then should simply filter with `ReportVisit.objects.filter(report__foo__bar=qux)` instead of `Visit.objects.filter(foo__bar=qux)`, so look "through" the `report` model.

Comment: Perfect, in my case it was results = ReportVisit.objects.filter(
            report__isnull=False, 
            report__in=reports
        )

Comment: @Spirconi: I would really advise *not* to do that, since that creates subqueries, and some databases handles these inefficiently. By filtering on the related model, the database works with a ` JOIN` and `WHERE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try from the other direction:

```
Visit.objects.filter(report__isnull=False)
```